# spark scala - string feature extraction to compute svd

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, feature-extraction, svd

I have a csv in this format:

```
doy|uuid|gender|conf|age_range|cat1|cat1score|cat2|cat2score|cat3|cat3score|main_hour_range|main_location|
```

In order to compute svd I need a RowMatrix

val mat: RowMatrix = ...
that i supposed to create with something like this:

```
val inputData = sc.textFile("my.csv").map{ line =>
  val parts = line.split("\t")
  (parts(0).toLong, parts(1).toInt, parts(2).toDouble...)
}
```

Here my problem:
How I can manage the features in my csv that have a string value, considering that my vector for the matrix need to be composed by numeric values?

1. parts(3) is a gender that can be: U (unknown) M (male) F (female)
2. parts(5) is a range in the string form: "19-49"
3. parts(13) is a generic string

Thanks in advance

Comment: So just like image processing applications, you will need to quantize your string data in the relationship that your Singular Value Decomposition is meant to evaluate.

Comment: Some examples to how do that?

Comment: To convert string to vector and process it, you are essentially trying to decompose the whole string into tokens/words and trying to evaluate the relationship between the words. If you want to see how string can be transformed into a vector, take a look at Spark's Mlib word2vec (which is a sort of a neural network), where words are translated into vectors.

Comment: @GameOfThrows ...thanks for the answer...actually my goals was not to create a vector but a mapping to convert string to numeric values: after some search I found this solutions: StringIndexer from the ML features/extraction package or the map->distinct->zipWithUniqueId transformations.

Comment: @fase_jhn its been a year, not sure if you are still looking for an answer on the same, or if you have figured it out. But, just using StringIndexer will not help you. You need to couple StringIndexer with HotEncoding(OneHotEncoder). Let me know if you still need more details.